# `apiVersion` is set to `v1beta1`. Still getting 'no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"'

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-web-services, kubectl, eks

Despite having explicitly set `apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`, why the following error when running any `kubectl` command (f.e. `kubectl version`)?

```
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: 
  decoding stdout: no kind "ExecCredential" is registered for version
    "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" in scheme "pkg/client/auth/exec/exec.go:62"
```

Here's the gist of `$HOME/.kube/config`:

```yml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      certificate-authority-data: CLUSTER_CERT
      server: https://CLUSTER_GID.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com
    name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/NAME
contexts:
  - context:
      cluster: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/NAME
      user: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/NAME
    name:
users:
  - name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/NAME
    user:
      exec:
        apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
        args:
        - --backend
        - pass
        - exec
        - PROFILE
        - --
        - aws-iam-authenticator
        - token
        - -i
        - CLUSTER_ID
        - --role
        - arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/ROLE
        command: aws-vault
        env: null
        interactiveMode: IfAvailable
        provideClusterInfo: false
```

`aws-vault` itself is working. F.e. this returns the expected: `aws-vault --backend=pass exec PROFILE -- aws s3 ls`

Tool versions:

- AWS CLI 2.15.33 (Python/3.11.8 Linux/5.15.0-1053-aws exe/aarch64.ubuntu.20)
- kubectl 1.26.3
- aws-iam-authenticator 0.5.0
- aws-vault 7.2.0

---

Some of the resources I tried to get help from:

- [A question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73744199/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-getting-credentials-decoding-stdout-no-kind).
- Tip from [related GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920#issuecomment-1460252536) doesn't apply as `apiVersion` in `.kube/config` already is set to `v1beta1`.